# using date_sub function dynamically to filter - PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a application which provides the application_run_date as string, which I was planning to convert to date format and use the same to apply the filter on dataframe. However I am running into an issue mentioned below.

Input Dataframe:

```
        raw_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
         (999,"2021-09-01","Buy_A",10),
         (999,"2021-09-02","Buy_B",15),
         (999,"2021-09-03","Buy_C",20),
         (999,"2011-09-04","Buy_D",100)
        ],
        ("cust", "cust_date","purchase","value")
        )
```

Error:

```
Reason: [ cannot resolve '`2021-09-04`' given input columns: [cust, cust_date, purchase, value] ]
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_sub
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

run_date = to_date(application_run_date,'yyyy-MM-dd')  # application_run_date is string, in this case provides a value 2021-09-04 as string
days_to_subtract =1 

final_data = raw_dataframe.filter(raw_dataframe["cust_date"].between(date_sub(run_date, days_to_subtract), run_date))
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) takes as first parameter a *column*. If you provide a string (for example `'2021-09-04'`) this string will be interpreted as *column name*, not as value.

If you want to string to be interpreted as value you have to convert it to a constant column using [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html).

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
run_date = F.to_date(F.lit(application_run_date),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

As a side note: you should avoid using `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` as it might hide standard functions like [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) or [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max). It is better to use `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`.